# Use of chosen inside modal (a4j:outputPanel) doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jsf, modal-dialog, richfaces, jquery-chosen

I'm new to jQuery and I try to use select chosen input inside a modal using `<a4j:outputPanel>` but it doesn't work.

This my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/docsupport/prism.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-no-conflict.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jstz.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showEditProductModal(visible) {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#addProductModal').modal(visible ? 'show' : 'hide');
        });
    }
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
</script>
</ui:define>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/chosen.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/docsupport/prism.css" />

<!-- Add/Edit product modal -->
<a4j:outputPanel id="addProductModal"
                 layout="block"
                 styleClass="modal modal-large hide fade">
    <h:form id="editProductModalForm" prependId="false" styleClass="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>Ajouter un produit</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding: 10px; max-height: 500px;">
            <div class="container-fluid"
                 style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <table border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <td>Brands</td>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                <select id="chzn-select"
                                        style="width:350px;"
                                        multiple="multiple"
                                        class="chzn-select"
                                        data-placeholder="Select an option...">

                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <option value="">OPT1</option>
                                    <option value="">OPT2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer" style="text-align: center;">
            <a id="cancelEditProductButton"
               href="#"
               class="btn btn-primary"
               data-dismiss="modal">
                #{common.COMMON_Cancel}
            </a>

            <a4j:commandButton id="saveEditProductButton"
                               type="button"
                               value="#{common.COMMON_Save}"
                               styleClass="btn btn-danger"
                               onclick="showWaitPane(true);
                                       showEditProductModal(false);"
                               oncomplete="showWaitPane(false);"
                               reRender="dataTableForm" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

When I put the select chosen outside the modal it work fine but without a `$.noConflict();` on jquery-no-conflict.js. The problem in this case is that the modal doesn't appears on click.

Do you have any suggestion or idea about it?

Comment: You have written many `<script>` tags inside another `<script>` tag forming invalid markup. Please fix it.

Comment: RichFaces already has modal panel and select components, why not use those? You haven't shown which panel is supposed to be showing and what the javascript does, are those events even triggered?. Please edit your question.

Comment: Ok i am trying to put it inside rich:modalPanel

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did a mistake in copying code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/docsupport/prism.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jquery-no-conflict.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/jstz.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showEditProductModal(visible) {
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $('#addProductModal').modal(visible ? 'show' : 'hide');
        });
    }
    $('.chzn-select').chosen();
</script>
```

Comment: Is this your answer or did you mean to update the code in your question?